# Can someone please identify this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Photo taken April 27 in Savannah Georgia [image]

Comment: Do you know anything about the flowers?

Comment: I'm not sure that it has flowers, I think it might just be a leafy shrub. That's why I'm having such a hard time figuring out what it is. :(

Comment: It looks a lot like a Muehlenbeckia species to me. More commonly known as the Australian Wire Vine.

Comment: @MrG That looks exactly right! Thank you so much!!